# C++ how to split string with alphabets and numbers

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a need to split the following string into their corresponding alpahbets and numbers

```
CH1000003
ABC000123
WXYZ10001
```

Results I want are

```
st1: CH
st2: 1000003

st1: ABC
st2: 000123

st1: WXYZ
st2: 10001
```

Now I do have a working code but the amount of code I have written seems a bit too much. There has to be an easy way. Perhaps somehow use regex in C++? Suggestions?

My code:

```
    std::string idToCheckStr="CH1000003";

    //find length of string
    int strLength = idToCheckStr.length();
    cout << "idToCheckStr: " << idToCheckStr <<endl;
    cout << "strLength   : " << strLength <<endl;

    string::iterator it;
    int index = 0;
    for ( it = idToCheckStr.begin() ; it < idToCheckStr.end(); it++ ,index++)
    {   
        //check where the numbers start in the string
        if (std::isdigit(*it) != 0)
        {
            cout<< "FOUND NUMBER!" <<endl;
            cout<< index << ": " << *it <<endl;
            break;
        }
            
         cout<< index << ": " << *it <<endl;
    }
    
    std::string firstPartStr = idToCheckStr.substr (0,index);
    cout << "firstPartStr: " << firstPartStr <<endl;
    
    std::string secondPartStr = idToCheckStr.substr (index,strLength);
    cout << "secondPartStr: " << secondPartStr <<endl;

OUTPUT:
idToCheckStr: CH1000003
strLength   : 9
0: C
1: H
FOUND NUMBER!
2: 1
firstPartStr: CH
secondPartStr: 1000003
```

Comment: Yes, regex is an option.

Comment: You do work too hard. `size_t first_digit = idToCheckStr.find_first_of("0123456789");`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik oh man that was too easy. lol. Yup definitely the easiest answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to igor.

```
    size_t first_digit = idToCheckStr.find_first_of("0123456789");
    cout << "first_digit: " << first_digit <<endl;
    
    std::string str1 = idToCheckStr.substr (0,first_digit);
    cout << "str1: " << str1 <<endl;
    
    std::string str2 = idToCheckStr.substr (first_digit,idToCheckStr.length());
    cout << "str2: " << str2 <<endl;

OUTPUT:
first_digit: 2
str1: CH
str2: 1000003
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the simple ways to handle your problem.
I find this more understandable for you.

```
    string s = "CH1000003";
    // cin >> s; if you waant to read the input
    
    string st1 = "", st2 = "";
    for(auto ch : s) {
        if(isdigit(ch)) st2 += ch;
        else if(isalpha(ch)) st1 += ch;
        else {} // if you want something else
    }
    
    cout << "st1: " << st1 << endl;
    cout << "st2: " << st2 << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed use regular expressions for this:

- The pattern would be `([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)`, i.e. any combination of 1 or more uppercase letters followed by any combination of 1 or more numbers. The parentheses allow you to capture those 2 groups to be able to access them later on.
- `std::regex_match(line, matches, pattern)` takes an input `line`, and tries to match it against a `pattern`. If it can, stores the matches in a `std::smatch` array; where the first entry is always the whole match, and the successive ones are for each capturing group. If it can't, it just returns `false`.
- Should you need to relax the regular expression, e.g. allowing white spaces before, after, or in the middle of the input string, you could do it easily just changing the pattern: `\s*([A-Z]+)\s*([0-9]+)\s*`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/fxe9qYW4s)

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <regex>  // regex_match, smatch
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string line{};
    std::regex pattern{R"(([A-Z]+)([0-9]+))"};
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        std::smatch matches{};
        if (std::regex_match(line, matches, pattern)) {
            std::cout << fmt::format("line = '{}', alphabets = '{}', numbers = '{}'\n",
                matches[0].str(), matches[1].str(), matches[2].str());
        }
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   line = 'CH1000003', alphabets = 'CH', numbers = '1000003'
//   line = 'ABC000123', alphabets = 'ABC', numbers = '000123'
//   line = 'WXYZ10001', alphabets = 'WXYZ', numbers = '10001'
```